# Recording of a desktop application on linux using Jmeter

Tags: linux, jmeter, desktop

I want to record human actions on a desktop application which is on Linux. I tried changing network setting by adding proxy as localhost and port as 8888. But no luck so far.can u please suggest, how to do recording of a desktop application on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case your application doesn't respect system-wide proxy settings, consult application developers and ask them how to configure the app to use proxy.

You can also try setting [`http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/set-up-proxy-http-proxy-environment-variable/)

If this doesn't help you can capture the application traffic using a sniffer tool like [tcpdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), export captured packets into .pcap file and convert them to JMeter script using [BlazeMeter Converter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/) tool